# View uploaded image in a laravel blade which is running on a php artisan serve server

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, laravel-blade

I have uploaded an image in laravel to the folder storage/uploads/profile.
The project is running in a php artisan serve server on wamp.
I need to view the image in a view blade. I used the code in the view blade

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/uploads/profile/'.$data->profile_picture) }}>
```

But the image is not displaying. When i inspected in the browser, the url is like

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/profile/image.jpg">
```

Help please.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call storage path use **storage_path** [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-storage-path)

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('uploads/profile/'.$data->profile_picture) }}>
```

or you can use laravel **storage:link** [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)
run this command it will create virtual directory in your public folder
so you can use like below

`php artisan storage:link`

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/profile/'.$data->profile_picture) }}>
```

or using **Storage::url()**

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url('/storage/uploads/profile/'.$data->profile_picture) }}" alt="{{ $images->filename }}" />
```

Comment: Still cant view the image. When inspected, its like  <img src="C:\wamp64\www\court-software\storage\uploads/profile/image.jpg">

Comment: @Rahul i have given 3rd option if its not worked you have to move your profile path into `storage/app/public/profile` then run this `php artisan storage:link` then you can use simply `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/profile/'.$data->profile_picture) }}>`

Comment: Do i need to change the storage path in my controller?

Comment: try 3rd option or you have to change path in controller also

Comment: I used the first method and then i inspected an d copied the link. When i open it in a new tab, the image appears. Then why dont it appears in the blade?

Comment: Please move to your path into ` storage/app/public` folder then easy https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/show-images-from-storage-folder

Comment: still doesnt work. Url while inspecting is like <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/profile/image.jpg"> ..... But when i copy the link and replace the 127.0.0.1:8000 with localhost/project , the image shows